# Using spring converter in @RequestBody

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc, jackson

Is it possible to enforce Converter ( org.springframework.core.convert.converter.Converter) to finish json object mapping?

Json code example:

```
{
 "name": "somename",
 "customObject": id
}
```

where somename - string, id - integer value

mapping to :

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgConstructor
public class ParentObject{
    private String name;
    private CustomObject customObject; 
}
```

Converter code example:

```
@Component
public class CustomObjectConverter implements Converter<String, CustomObject>{

    @Autowired
    private CustomObjectService customObjectService;

    @Override
    public CustomObject convert(String arg0) {
        Long id = Long.parseLong(arg0);
        return customObjectService.findById(id);
    }   
}
```

What I want to achieve is to map that json to the object which will have automatically fetched from db nested object.

Comment: I think it is not a good idea to use db call inside converter. but to answer your question you just need to use ObjectMapper in jackson to convert json string to json object

Comment: Your comment intrigued me, it could be off topic but I'm curious what is wrong with call to service from converter component. I can't find any dangerous spots in such flow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should implement your own `JacksonCustomMapper`, by extending `JsonMapper` and then registering it into the set of `HttpMessageConverters`. But, I do not recommend to pollute the default conversion, you could pass in the `@RequestBody` an incomplete json and Jackson will parse it to your object, it would be sufficient to not pass wrong keys in your json object... An example (among thousands) here: http://magicmonster.com/kb/prg/java/spring/webmvc/jackson_custom.html. Enjoy it :-)

Answer (score 2):

I think there is a better way to solve this problem.
All you need is to add one more implementation:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.util.Converter
```

And put an annotation over your object:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonDeserialize;
...
@JsonDeserialize(converter = CustomObjectConverter.class)
private CustomObject customObject;
```

As a result, your code will look like this.
Model:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgConstructor
public class ParentObject{
   private String name;

   @JsonDeserialize(converter = CustomObjectConverter.class)
   private CustomObject customObject; 
}
```

Converter:

```
@Component
public class CustomObjectConverter implements 
  org.springframework.core.convert.converter.Converter<String, CustomObject>, 
  com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.util.Converter<String, CustomObject>{

   @Autowired
   private CustomObjectService customObjectService;

   @Override
   public CustomObject convert(String arg0) {
       Long id = Long.parseLong(arg0);
       return customObjectService.findById(id);
   }

   @Override
   public JavaType getInputType(TypeFactory typeFactory) {
       return typeFactory.constructType(String.class);
   }

   @Override
   public JavaType getOutputType(TypeFactory typeFactory) {
       return typeFactory.constructType(CustomObject.class);
   }
}
```